# Java String formatting question about taking 3 instance variables and formatting them as HH:MM:SS + more

Tags: java, string, format

as the description say's i have 3 instance variables

```
private int Hours;
private int Minutes;
private int Seconds;
```

i have already completed the part of setting and getting said values, but i am rather stuck on the part where i need to format this into the HH:MM:SS format with leading zeros for the values that are less than 0, we are assuming that we are using a scanner to allow a user to input whatever we want.

thanks!

heres the method its being done under

```
public String toString()
{
//dont know what to do to format it as wanted
//return "the formatted output"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few options. One would be to create an instance of LocalTime (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#of-int-int-int-) and then format it (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#format-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-)

Or you could just use String format - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit premature, I answered for a date. Can't see where to delete my answer!

Comment: Okay, sorted it by changing to LocalTime rather than LocalDate :-)